# What is OpenStack?

Tags: openstack

I am a beginner of Ubuntu, who used to be an MS-Windows OS user.

And I registered to visit Canonical’s 2015 OpenStack Roadshow.

I think prior knowledge is required to understand what is announced.

Where can I find it?

HELLOVENUS, Fantagio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenStack is a set of software tools for building and managing cloud
>   computing platforms for public and private clouds. Backed by some of
>   the biggest companies in software development and hosting, as well as
>   thousands of individual community members, many think that OpenStack
>   is the future of cloud computing.<sup>[What is OpenStack?](http://opensource.com/resources/what-is-openstack)</sup>

Basically OpenStack allows you to create your own clound.

For more information, and to get the software, visit [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Openstack is huge number of open source projects(software) working together to bring up cloud (Storage+Compute+Network) on generic servers.